# Wrap div-tag around posts in page

Tags: posts, pages, single

I'm creating a new Theme from scratch and I'm currently stuck with my post-page. I want a div-tag around every single post in that page. But I can't find the code that helps me with that.

What is curretly the case:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2></h2> <!-- Start post-1 -->
    <p></p>
    <p></p> <!-- End post-1 -->
    <h2></h2> <!-- Start post-2 -->
    <p></p>
    <p></p> <!-- End post-2 -->
</div>
```

What I want:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="post"> <!-- Start post-1 -->
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div> <!-- End post-1 -->
    <div id="post> <!-- Start post-2 -->
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div> <!-- End post-2 -->
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are showing the output html. What we need to help you is your template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen if you proceed with the following syntax?

```
<div id="container">
<?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </article > <!-- /#post-<?php the_post_ID(); ?> -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div> <!-- /#container -->
```

The additional things added:

- [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class)
- HTML5 semantic tag `<article>`, and
- [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

And:

> **Never** ever repeat same ID on a single view

Comment: Thank you for opening my Eyes! That code helped me alot! I have one question thoe ... why shouldn't I use the same ID if I want to style them all the same? Because I don't really want to style the <article> tag.

Comment: What happen when there're two people in a class named 'Pelle'? We simply rename them to distinguish one from the other. So don't mess up with IDs for selecting elements. Let's use other attribute like `class`. Pass classes inside the `post_class()` as `post_class('regular-post')` and select them from CSS: `.regular-post{ /*some rule*/ }` and do whatever style you want.